# create a git folder and sync to existing github repo without git clone

Tags: git, github

I have a folder structure in my laptop A (not a git folder). 6 months ago, I copied this folder into laptop B then I started working on that laptop B. I haven’t touched my laptop A since then.

I created my repo in github then push all my works from laptop B to github.  Everything works fine so far. the local (laptop B) and remote is synced.

Here’s the case : I don’t have access to my laptop B - I left my laptop B at the office and now I’m at home with my laptop A with the old data. I want to sync from laptop A to my github.

I can make a local fresh copy by using git clone , but this is secondary option because the connection is slow and will took a long time to get all the data from scratch. I only want to pull the modified files.

First I made it as git folder use ‘git init’ then ‘git remote add origin …..’ . But then how can i do this so I only need to pull and replace local data only for those files that has been modified (not cloning the whole things). Is it possible ?

Comment: It's not possible to fetch only changed data in your case easily. You can, however, do a [_shallow clone_](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) of the project from GitHub. The _shallow clone_ will transfer only the latest commit from the remote (without the entire history). This makes it efficient in terms of data transfer. Use `git clone --depth 1 --branch [remote-branch] [remote-url]` to perform a _shallow clone_.